# Angularjs not reloading page with the right json file

Tags: angularjs

I'm storing data and language terms for the website with json, and depending on the language selected i load the adequate file. The problem is when i switch the language, only the adress in the adressbar change without reloading the right json file.

#### factory.js

```
app.factory('PostsFactory', function ($http, $q, $timeout) {
    var factory = {
        posts: false,
        find: function (lang) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            if (factory.posts !== false) {
                deferred.resolve(factory.posts);
            } else {
                $http.get(lang+'/json.js').success(function (data, status) {
                    factory.posts = data;
                    $timeout(function () {
                        deferred.resolve(factory.posts);
                    })

                }).error(function (data, status) {
                    deferred.reject('error')
                });
            }

            return deferred.promise;
        },
        get: function (id, lang) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var post = {};
            var posts = factory.find(lang).then(function (posts) {
                angular.forEach(posts, function (value, key) {
                    if (value.id == id) {
                        post = value;
                    };
                });
                deferred.resolve(post);
            }, function (msg) {
                deferred.reject(msg);
            })

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }

    return factory;
})
```

### controller

#### posts.js

```
app.controller('PostsCtrl', function ($scope, PostsFactory, $rootScope, $routeParams) {
    $rootScope.loading = true;
    lang = $routeParams.lang;
    PostsFactory.find(lang).then(function (posts) {

        $rootScope.loading = false;
        $scope.posts = posts;

    }, function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    });
});
```

#### post.js

```
app.controller('PostCtrl', function ($scope, PostsFactory, $routeParams, $rootScope) {

    $rootScope.loading = true;

    SounanFactory.get($routeParams.id, $routeParams.lang).then(function (post) {
        $rootScope.loading = false;
        $scope.title = post.title;
        $scope.text = post.text;
        $scope.image = post.image;
        $scope.id = post.id;
    }, function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    });
});
```

#### app.js

```
var app = angular.module('Posts', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/:lang/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/posts.html', controller: 'PostsCtrl'})
    .when('/:lang/post/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/post.html', controller: 'PostCtrl'})
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/en'
    });
})
```

#### posts.html

```
<div ng-hide="loading">
    <a href="#/en/post/{{post.id}}" ng-repeat="post in posts " class="{{post.class}}">
        <div class="title">{{post.title}}</div>
        <div class="index">{{post.id}}</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

#### index.html

```
<body ng-app="Posts">
    <div ng-show="loading">Loading ...</div>
    <div class="container" ng-view></div>
    <a href="#/fr" >FR</a> 
    <a href="#/en" >EN</a>
</body>
```

Comment: You are going to need to paste the relevant code into your question

Comment: i've shared it in the link above (pastebin)

Comment: I know but they frown on just links. Links break.

Comment: Can you narrow it down?

Answer (score 0):

In your posts.js have you tried adding `$scope.$apply()` underneath `$scope.posts = posts;` in `posts.js` and again under `$scope.id = post.id;` in `post.js`?

The problem that you're facing is probably due to Angular's digest cycle and the bizarre way you're trying to pass values around through promises/objects/wizardry.

I mean, it's kind of the least of your worries. I know nothing of the project but there are a few things that could be causing an issue here.

- Why do you have a `$timeout()` without a time?
- Why are you setting a `lang` var and then immediately using it instead of just passing it through?
- Why are you assigning a posts member of your factory and then using it immediately instead of just passing it through?
- You should be using `ng-href` for dynamic url's

Let us know how you get on.